# Make nice URL for calendar

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I am trying to create a nice looking url for my calendar site.
But I can't get it to work properly.

This is my URL:

> http://mydomain.com/admin/calendar?year=2013&month=november

...and I want it to look like this:

> http://mydomain.com/admin/calendar/2013/november

The "calender"-folder is **not** a real folder and the .htaccess file is located in the admin-folder and **not** in the root of my website.

I am currently using this code:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Make sure not to rewrite real files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .+ - [L]

# Removes PHP extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]

# Make new URL
RewriteBase /admin/
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /admin/calendar/calendar?year=$1&month=$2 [L]
```

Any idea why this doesn't work, and how to get it to work? :D

Thanks :)
TheYaXxE

Comment: What is location of above .htaccess file?

Comment: http://mydomain.com/admin/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code in your `admin/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /admin/

# Make sure not to rewrite real files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Make new URL
RewriteRule ^calendar/([^/]+)/([^/]*)/?$ calendar.php?year=$1&month=$2 [NC,L,QSA]

# Removes PHP extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: a "The requested URL /admin/calendar/2013/november was not found on this server" appears

Comment: But when you try to open: `/admin/calendar?year=2013&month=november` does it load?

Comment: Yes. The site does load

Comment: Is `admin/calendar` a directory?

Comment: No. But the file is called calendar.php.
Only admin/ is a directory

Comment: Woho! Now the function seems to work! :D thank you very much mate! :)
Now the only thing that seems to be wrong is that the site think that the stylesheet is located in 2013/css/style.css. Right now I am using relative URL's. Should i change it to absolute, like: <link href="http://mydomain.com/admin/css/style.css"> instead of <link href="css/style.css"> ? :)

Comment: Yes definitely start using absolute URLs in css, js, images. Relative URLs can and will break while using pretty URL schemes like this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /admin/calendar/calendar?year=$1&month=$2
```